# DataTable Foreach - Getting to Table Data but only returning one result

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I've got a DataTable (sourced from a local db) and I'm trying to compare the "QuestionID" in the Answers table to the Id of the current Question so that it displays the four answers related to that question in a RadioButtonList (ASP.Net).

It's working up to a point in that it gets the first result that matches and puts in it the radio button list but it doesn't get the other three that match. Why? Tearing my hair out staring at this piece of code.

```
DataView dvQuestion = (DataView) sqldataQuestions.Select(new DataSourceSelectArguments());
lblQuestion.Text = string.Format(dvQuestion[questionCount]["QuestionText"].ToString());

DataView dvAnswers = (DataView) sqldataAnswers.Select(new DataSourceSelectArguments());
DataTable tblAnswers = dvAnswers.ToTable();
string value;

foreach (DataRow dr in tblAnswers.Rows)
{
      int questionID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["QuestionID"]);
      if (questionID == PgeNum)
      {
          string ansTxt = dr["AnswerText"].ToString();
          rblAnswers.Items.Add(ansTxt);
      }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged it or just *"staring at this piece of code"*?

Comment: What if only one entry is present in the datatable corresponding to that question ID ? Have a look.

Comment: Thanks for the response Havey. The Answers table has four rows with QuestionIDs with values of 1, which is the value I'm comparing for in the above. It gets the first row with 1 in the QuestionID column but then skips or can't see the others. The count for tblAnswers.Rows is 1 even though there are 27 entries in the Answers db.

Comment: Just remove the `questionID == PgeNum` check, and let all Answer be added into `rbl`. Just for testing purpose that whether it has all four answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.This will filter the rows where QuestionId is equal to pgeNum. Than you can loop on rows to get your desired results.

```
DataRow[] rows =  tblAnswers.Select("QuestionID = " + PgeNum);
 if (rows.Length != 0)
    {
      foreach (DataRow dr in rows)
      {      
        string ansTxt = dr["AnswerText"].ToString();
        rblAnswers.Items.Add(ansTxt);
       }

     }
```

Comment: Mairaj - thank you so much for your help.  I put your code in and it made me look at the Select statement I had on the ASPX page - the WHERE clause was "WHERE ([Id] = @Id)" and that seems to have been what was forcing only one row's text to be returned. It's so great to talk a problem out here, it just forces you to look at a problem in a new way. It's made my morning not a waste - thank you so much!

Comment: @user2966419 Thats what every one was expecting :)